# Sails.js Waterline Model Storage

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to store a large chunk of text as part of a model in Sails.js. However, it seems that the text is getting cut off after some length. Is there a limit set on how long the 'string' type can hold in a model? If so, what's the best way around it? For reference, I'm using sails-mysql as an adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, String is only 255 chars long on default (because thats the default length in the most databases).

Try to use

```
myfield: {
    type: "text"
}
```

As attribute - this should work.

(See: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Attributes.html)

Comment: Hmmm... They don't show it in this table for some reason.    http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations

Comment: That link is dead. Use this link as of lately. There's also longText and mediumText...  http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
field: {
    type: 'ref'
}
this creates longtext in mysql .